# How to change a part of view in JavaFx

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I've got a view (SplitPane horizontaly seperated). So lets name these two parts lowerAnchorPane and upperAnchorPane. In upperUnchorPane I've got a button. I want the application after pressing that button to switch lowerAnchorPane with another AnchorPane created in FXML file. I want to achive this in function showPatients() but it seems not working, can you suggest me any solutions? I don't know any other way to load fxml file

```
public class MainController {

    private Patient model;
    @FXML
    private Button newPatientButton;
    @FXML
    private Button newVisitButton;
    @FXML
    private Button showVisitsButton;
    @FXML
    private Button showPatientsButton;
    @FXML
    private AnchorPane lowerAnchorPane;

    public void initData(Patient model)
    {
        this.model = model;
    }


    @FXML
    void showPatients(ActionEvent event) throws IOException { // when button pressed
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/fxml/ListOfPatients.fxml"));
        lowerAnchorPane = loader.load();

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can inject the `SplitPane` and replace the existing lower anchor pane with the one you load:

```
@FXML
private SplitPane splitPane ; // with the corresponding fx:id in the fxml file

@FXML
void showPatients(ActionEvent event) throws IOException { // when button pressed
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/fxml/ListOfPatients.fxml"));
    lowerAnchorPane = loader.load();

    // assuming the existing pane is the second one in the split pane:
    splitPane.getItems().set(1, lowerAnchorPane);
}
```

Comment: An set() function contains two parameters: index and the thing we want to replace. How did you that the lowerSplitPane is number 1 (index) ?

Comment: @Michael213 I assumed it was the second one added, since you said it was the lower one (of two).